# Trouble querying List<String> child field in GAE JDO

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, jdoql

I've seen many examples but none seem to work for my issue.  I'm using JDO in GAE (Java). I'm not geting any error messages.  I'm just not getting a result when I know there should be or else the result matches objects with an empty List for dispatchId.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here's my relevant class code:

```
public class Department {

  @PrimaryKey
  @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

...  

  // a list of codes that a department might be identified by
  @Persistent
  private List<String> dispatchId; 

}
```

I'm trying to find a Department whose dispatchId List contains a specific dispatchId code.  My Java servlet code is:

```
String dispatchId = "1353000"; // may contain letters and/or numbers
Query q = pm.newQuery(Department.class, ":dispatchId.contains(dispatchId)");
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
List<Department> depts = (List<Department>) q.execute(dispatchId);
```

In the GAE Datastore viewer (live on GAE) the dispatchId field for my test department looks like this (in case this helps):

[u'1353000', u'0566940', u'0566936', u'1368496']

Thanks again for any input... John

Answer (score 3):

Hello did you still looking for the answer?

Here is a solution for it:

```
String dispatchId = "someId";
Query query = pm.newQuery(Department.class);
query.setFilter("dispatchId == '"+ dispatchId + "'");
List<Department> depts = (List<Department>) query.execute();
```

Here you would need a single quote to enclose the parameter.